# MYSQl Select Regex Syntax 3 hours still can't find the issue

Tags: php, mysqli

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE sid=$steering_committee AND project_num = REGEX '/^$qmonth/'");
```

project_num is an 11 char string with the month being the first 2 chars. I want to filter based on the $month passed from form input and display.

I've also tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE sid=$steering_committee AND project_num = REGEXP '^[" . $qmonth . "]'");
```

doesn't like syntax on this either

Comment: "doesn't like syntax" is pretty vague. Please post the precise error message you get.

Comment: Also post the query assignments. Since you use string concatenations instead of printf constructs this might be important.

Comment: Square braces match a set of chars in a single position, not a series of chars.  That is why your second is invalid, in addtion to having the = sign before REGEXP.  That is if your month was 10, "^[10]" would match numbers starting with either a 0 or a 1, not specifically numbers starting with 10.  Numbers starting with 10 is "^10".

Comment: Any chance my answer helped?

Comment: Yes this was very helpful, unfortunately the project took a different turn and I ended up not using this section of code. Thank you for your help anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Why not `SUBSTRING()`?  I think it would be faster anyway:

```
SUBSTRING(project_num, 1, 2) = '$qmonth'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE sid=$steering_committee AND project_num REGEXP '^$qmonth'
```

Then ask your self a few questions.

Should I be using prepared statements instead of variable interpolation?  Or, do I just like being hacked?

Should I really be using a REGEXP, which can never be indexed, or would a very indexable prefix match work just as well "AND project_num LIKE '$qmonth%'"?  Or do you really dislike snappy web pages?